# How to make different custom post layouts?

Tags: posts, templates, css

I am new to wordpress, and have encountered some difficulty in making my own custom layouts. I'm using _S framework (underscore.me) as well as Custom Post Templates plugin.

I'm using custom fields to inject images above the title of posts currently, and that's worked so far but I encounter problems when trying to make index-only custom layouts for post's as well as applying CSS to the custom fields.

The custom index only post appearances are about three in number, one of which is how I want posts to look like by default.

What I'd like to know is which files should I be looking at, and some guidance on how I should go about modifying (as some elements seem not to change when I wrap/apply CSS to them) to change the index only appearance as I currently am able to modify the appearance of the post page itself.

If more info is required I can post it

Comment: Do you mean "custom layouts for posts" or "layouts for custom post types"? (In the latter case, this may help:  http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Hierarchy .)

Comment: What support does underscore include for Layouts?

Comment: Listing posts with custom markup for each post in a list, for example the category or pages or index or frontpage, could be done with a custom post taxonomy that is assigned to that post. Something like [this](https://clicknathan.com/web-design/make-your-own-custom-post-formats-wordpress/) or [this](https://generatewp.com/taxonomy/). It is the term taxonomy that is attached to the post as a "label" if you like. You can then create different markup and styling for such a label and assign it to the posts you like.

Answer (score 2):

To rephrase, I believe what you're asking is how can you have a different style or template for your custom post types when they are displaying as a list?

It looks like the Custom Post Templates plugin you're using only allows you to switch templates for the single view of a post, not the listing of the posts, which is what I think you mean when you say index?

If you just need a way to style your posts separately, this depends on your theme, but in TwentyTwelve and TwentyThirteen, in index.php, it has the loops that, if posts exists, displays them, or displays a message if there are no posts. If you just need a class to use so that you can style each post type's archive separately, you can use a PHP if statement to check for your custom post type and add a class if it's true. Here's an example. Let's say my custom post type is called recipe_posts, and I want to add a class called "recipe-archive" for when those posts are being displayed in list form, I would write something like this in TwentyThirteen's index.php:

```
<div id="primary" class="content-area <?php if(get_post_type() == recipe_posts): ?>recipes-archive<?php endif; ?>">
    <div id="content" class="site-content" role="main">
            <?php if ( have_posts() ) : ?>

                <?php /* The loop */ ?>
                <?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
                    <?php get_template_part( 'content', get_post_format() ); ?>
                <?php endwhile; ?>

                <?php twentythirteen_paging_nav(); ?>

            <?php else : ?>
                <?php get_template_part( 'content', 'none' ); ?>
            <?php endif; ?>

    </div><!-- #content -->
</div><!-- #primary -->
```

Here I added a class to where "content-area" is with `<?php if(get_post_type() == recipe_posts): ?>recipes-archive<?php endif; ?>` but really, you can use this method where you need it to make styling easier. Now if you want to change templates, by default, in TwentyTwelve/Thirteen, it uses content.php that gets called in index.php. You can use the same PHP if statement if you want to swap out `<?php get_template_part(); ?>` with something else.

Hope that helps. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

There's 2 questions you're asking which relate to **Layouts** and **Styling Custom Templates**.

**Layouts**

You can change the layout using code in the template files or conditionally from your child themes functions.php file using a filter however this depends on your parent theme.

The code for this may vary depending on the theme you're using and the support it includes for different layout options.

**Custom Body Class**

You can also add a custom body class directly to the templates or from your functions file conditionally for the archive or single template file.

Use this code directly in a template file

```
add_filter( 'body_class', 'add_custom_body_class_template' );

function add_custom_body_class_template( $classes ) {

$classes[] = 'archive-body-class';

return $classes;

}
```

Use this code in your child themes functions fle:

```
add_filter( 'body_class', 'add_custom_body_class_conditionally' );

function add_custom_body_class_conditionally( $classes ) {

if ( is_page_template('template_file_name.php') ) {

$classes[] = 'custom-body-class';

return $classes;

    }
}
```

Change the [conditional tag](http://codex.wordpress.org/Conditional_Tags) to match the templates you want to style.

Source http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/body_class